# algorithm for implementing DFA as a linked list

Tags: java, c++, c, linked-list, dfa

I want to know how to implement a DFA as a linked list in C/C++/Java.

Answer (score 3):

since every state can have several branches, you probably need more than one linked list. that means, every state has an array of n linked lists. so it's more like a tree structure with cycles than a simple linked list.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, but would be grossly inefficient. What you would do is to simply store all your states in a link list, and then each state would need to keep a transition table. The transition table would look something like:

```
'a' -> 2
'b' -> 5
```

where your alphabet is `{a,b}`, and 2 and 5 are the states stored at position 2 and 5 in the linked list. As I said, this is definitely NOT how you would want to implement a DFA, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came up in my mind is that,

create a  class/struct called *state* with two array components. one for the states that can reach our state and one for the ones that are reachable from our state. 
Then create a linked list whose elements are your states.

here's my implementation of this class

```
class state
{
    private:
        string stateName;
        vector<state> states_before_me;
        vector<state> states_after_me;
        state* next;

        //methods of this state

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Single linked list couldn't represent the DFA efficiently. You can think DFA as a directed weighted graph data structure as states are vertices, transitions are edges, transition symbols are weights. There are two main method to implement graph structure.

i) Adjacency list: It basically has V(Number of vertices) linked lists. Each link list contains vertices which has edge to corresponding vertex. If we have vertices `(1,2,3)` and edges `(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,3)` corresponding adjanceny list is:

```
1->2->3
2->1->3
3->3
```

ii) Adjacency matrix: It is a VxV matrix with every entry at (i,j) symbolize an edge from i to j. The same example above represented like(1 means there is edge, 0 mean there is not):

```
  1 2 3
1 0 1 1
2 1 0 1
3 0 0 1
```

But you must make little changes to these because your graph is weighted.

For list implementation you can change vertices in linklist to a struct which contains vertex and the weight of the edge connecting these vertices.

For matrix implementation you can place the weights directly into matrix instead of 0,1 values.

If you don't want to deal with the implementation of graph class there is libraries like Boost Graph Library which contains the two implementation and all the important graph algorithms DFS to Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. You can look it up from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html.